# What is Mordell's conjecture in simple terms?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am reading Ian Stewart's The Great Mathematical Problems, and come across the chapter regarding the Mordell's conjecture. After reading I couldn't draw a clear picture about the conjecture and also what really Faltings proved. Can anybody explain it in simple terms? Little bit of mathematics is fine. I do know elementary Diophantine analysis though.